# in Flutter when I call a showSnackBar, it keeps on showing until I refresh the page. It does not disappear by itself

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text('You dont have enough money'),
    ));
```

When I give it time it does not work as well. Can it be because I am calling it from a function?

Answer (score 0):

SnackBar has a property duration , use to duration property to set time till you want to show sSnackBar after tha it will disappear automatically.

```
   _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text('You dont have enough money'),
    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
   ));
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not work as I said. When I give duration it still does not go away.